# private key should be a PEM or plain PKSC1 terraform error using GCP provider

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

for some reason I can't get around this auth error using the GCP provider.

`* google_compute_instance.abc1234: Error loading zone 'us-west1-a': Get https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxxxxx/zones/us-west1-a?alt=json: private key should be a PEM or plain PKSC1 or PKCS8; parse error: asn1: syntax error: sequence truncated`

My provider config is this:

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = "${file("/home/xxxxx/.gsutil/credstore2.json")}"
  project     = "xxxxx"
  region      = "us-west1"
}
```

and I do have valid creds in `credstore2.json` since I'm able to successfully use the gsutil and gcloud commands. I've also opened up the permission on that file but still get the same error.

Comment: What does your credstore2.json file start with? If it starts with `{"credentials": {` then these are the wrong type of credentials. If it starts with `{"type": "service_account",` these are the correct ones. For my terraform setup, I use an environment variable for credentials `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path/file`.

Comment: ah...they start with `{"credentials`...whats the other ones? New to GCP from AWs world here...

Comment: got it! created at SA account with the key...works now!

Comment: I received the same error with service account credentials stored in an environment variable... and pretty-printing the JSON resolved it for whatever reason.